# Create a navigation bar with their respected version either iOS 6 or iOS7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I am creating an app for both iOS6 and iOS7 in xcode5.  If it is possible to create a navigation bar with their respected version either iOS 6 or iOS7.

If my app is running in iOS6, i want to display this bar

[Notification center label http://imageshack.com/a/img593/9692/1zw5.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img593/9692/1zw5.png)

or

my app is running in iOS7, want to display this bar

[Notification center label http://imageshack.com/a/img34/9728/he1m.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img34/9728/he1m.png)

The above question is possible means, how could i change each and every buttons and switch iOS6 to iOS7 (for example: Switch, back button, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bother about the UI of iOS6 and iOS7, Use System Elements ( UINavigationbar, UISwitch ,UIbutton,etc..) their appearance will be change according to iOS version.

[image]
From Apple Doc:

`If business reasons require you to continue supporting iOS6 or earlier, you need to choose the most practical way to update the app for iOS7. The techniques you choose can differ, but the overall advice remains the same: First, focus on redesigning the app for iOS7. Then—if the redesign includes navigational or structural changes—bring these changes to the iOS6 version as appropriate`**(don’t restyle the iOS 6 version of the app to use iOS7 design elements, such as translucent bars or borderless bar buttons)**.`

reference: [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)